# Flutter : how i get data from firestore in List<String>?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

hi guys i'm trying to get data from my firestore database into `List<String>` for that i create variable `List<String> listCour;` and i use that instruction for get data from firestore

```
   Firestore.instance
    .collection('MATH')
    .document(doc.documentID)
    .collection("cours")
    .snapshots()
    .listen(
    (cour)=> cour.documents.forEach((doc){

           listCour.add(doc.documentID);                   
             })
          );
```

but the List has get no data !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using doc.data

```
listCour.add(doc.data);
```

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('MATH')
    .document(doc.documentID)
    .collection("cours")
    .getDocuments()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents...
    })
```

Comment: no data :( 
 i try any affection inside ` forEach((doc){ ---- } `
and didn't  working i don't know why